# How to tell if a page is 404 within the base constructor?

Tags: laravel, controller

I am trying to log page views in my Controller.php file:

```
class Controller extends BaseController
{
   function __construct()
  {

    $path = \URL::current();

    $insert = array
    (
      'ip' => utils__get_ip_address(),
      'session_id' => session()->getId(),
      'path' => $path,
      'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
    );

    DB::table("analytics")->insert($insert);
  }
}
```

This works great but I am unable to determine if the route being access currently is returning a 404.

1. Is there a way to see if this current request will yield a 404 at this level?
2. If not, what is a better way to log access views in a way that I can tell if it's a 404?

Thanks!

Comment: As I know if the request is 404 laravel won't redirect to a controller because the request wants an unknown controller but You can do it at Exceptions `Handler` If 404 does something.
if you want to know how, please tell me ur Laravel version.

Comment: @MohamedGamalEldin, I use laravel 8.

Comment: I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At `App\Exceptions\Handler.php` you will add these codes

```php
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException; // to know if it is not found exception or not

...
//After register() function
public function report(Throwable  $exception)
{
   if($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException){
      // You can do here anything you want
      dd("Not found from Handler");
   }
   parent::report($exception);
}
```

That's all,
Please tell me if everything is alright.

Comment: Doesnt seem to work :(

Comment: @coderama Can you share `root-app/app/Exceptions/Handler.php` file with me?

Comment: There is [my code](https://gist.github.com/mohamed-cpp/c2f0ed6ccf39d24436d4789f0077896e) from a refresh Laravel app

Comment: Mine is identical but it looks like I had to change this part: if($exception instanceof Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException){